# Problem related with the similarity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this problem which says:

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that only $A$ is similar to itself.Then  show that A is a scalar matrix, that is $A$ is of the form \begin{pmatrix}
a &0 \\ 
0 & a
\end{pmatrix}
?
My attempts: 
 Since $A$ is similar to itself,there exists an invertible matrix P such that A=
$P^{-1}AP$. Then I tried to solve it by choosing A and P of the form \begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
and \begin{pmatrix}
x &y \\ 
z & w
\end{pmatrix}
respectively. But I could not get the desired result. Please help. Thanks everyone in advance for your time.

Comment: Stop me if I'm wrong, but isn't every square matrix similar to itself?! (take the identity matrix for $P$)
May I suggest that you check the problem ?

Comment: @JulienB. Yes.But here the question says that A is only similar to itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

The matrix $A$ is similar *only* to itself. Thus $PAP^{-1}=A $ for all invertible $P.$ 
Use as $P$ the matrices:
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ P=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\ 1 &1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Is there any way to find P in two different forms ?

Comment: @learner: The answer means write out what this means when one takes for $P$ the first matrix, then (independently) write out what it means when one takes for $P$ the second matrix. The hypothesis is that it holds for _all_ invertible matrices, but it suffices to use that hypothesis just for those two to reach the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, that $A$ is only similar to itself means $PA=AP$ for all invertible matrix $P$. Therefore
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a+cx&b+dx\\ cy&dy\end{pmatrix}=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&y\end{pmatrix}}_{P}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}}_{A}=
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&y\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}a&ax+by\\c&cx+dy\end{pmatrix}
$$
for all $y\not=0$ and all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that every $2\times2$ matrix is similar either to a matrix of the form $$A=\pmatrix{a&0\cr0&b\cr}$$ or to a matrix of the form $$B=\pmatrix{a&1\cr0&a\cr}?$$ If so, then all you have to show is that $A$ is similar to $$\pmatrix{b&0\cr0&a\cr}$$ and $B$ is similar to $$\pmatrix{a&0\cr1&a\cr}$$ (and the latter follows from the theorem that every matrix is similar to its transpose).

Comment: That's using quite a lot of structure theory for a question that can be answered very basically. Also it is only valid for matrices over algebraically closed fields, which is not implied in the question.